# Signal when Task is finished (which content is calling asynchronous method)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I'm looking into Task functionality in C# for the first time. The reason I'm looking at it, is that I need control over a bunch of things my applications needs to do, and I need strict control over those "tasks". To be exact, I need to know when and if a given task was finished, I need also the ability to cancel the execution of the remeaning tasks if needed.

From what I read so far I can achive that if I use the synchronous code. So for example I have:

```
Task task = new Task(() => 
{
synchronousMethod();
});
task.Start();
```

That will work as expected, so I will know when this task is finished, as the code is being executed synchronously. So the task starts, the execution enters the synchronousMethod content, it runs to the end, returns to the Task code and it is being marked Complete. The problem starts when this method changes into asynchronous method. That method is being run in different thread, and so, even though the task might be marked as completed, the asynchronous method might still be not finished.

Even worse happens, when that asynchronous method will run internaly other methods that have asynchronous calls that I would also like to include as the part of the single task.

So my question is, if I can achieve the level of control I would like within the Task namespace. Ofcourse I can try and input certain callbacks that will be called at certain point, which will signal to me, the Task reached certain point, but if those tasks are in a significant number and I need to know which task is which that will not be as elegant solution as I'm interested in.

Any help/advise?

Comment: have you had a look at the await keyword?
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/hh156528.aspx)


`Task task = new Task(() => 
{
synchronousMethod();
});
task.Start();
await task;`